# I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Javascript/UI newbie....i keep getting Uncaught TypeError

```
i.)Uncaught  TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

ii.)Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Could  anyone please advise,i tried to google...I see people are advising to check if you have installed

```
i.)jquery.tool.min.js with core files(which i am assuming is a jquery.min.js) and

   ii.)jquery.min.js
```

Below aree the two Errors in detail:-

```
i.) swank_template_dp.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function(anonymous function) @ swank_template_dp.js:5f @ jquery.combo.min.js?v=4914987:2(anonymous function) 

ii.)eal_view.jsp?id=61922:830 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function(anonymous function) @ deal_view.jsp?id=61922:830j @ jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery-UI linked?

Comment: You haven't got jquery-ui installed. Have a read of something like https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: Perhaps it is script link ordering problem. Make clear that declare jquery to the top than jquery-ui.

Comment: Another common cause of this is loading multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: Looks like issue with missing script or sequence of scripts

Comment: Would you upload code snippet that declared script tags ?

Comment: So is jQuery UI referenced? You said people advised that, did you actually check?

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply. .....JQuery  UI is referenced.The problem happen when I am trying to use Datatables  JQUERY plugin.If I remove Datatables JQuery plug in ,I don't see th problem. Datatable..load fine but  ,chrome console shows Uncaught type Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download and add jquery UI, Here a link for latest version:
http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip

Comment: Thank   you  Dkouk,,,,,i was able to  solve this issue  by putting all  scripts above the top of the page

Comment: Great to hear that,  i think you can make my answer as correct :)